# Hard disk volumes are not automatically mounting in ubuntu

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I recently installed Ubuntu on my laptop which was previously running on windows. I have installed Ubuntu in my SSD and I have HDD installed in the CD drive slot. Now when I start the laptop and try to open the folders which are there on the HDD partitions, they fail to open and I have to mount the all the partitions in HDD to open those folders. (for SSD I don't have to mount any partitions).

How to solve this problem, so that I do not have to mount every time I switch on my laptop.

Ubuntu is installed on my laptop and version I am using is : Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS desktop

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; nor if you added entries in the file-system table (*fstab*) so they automount?  (*other automount options may exist for you as well; but given we don't know your product/release details we don't know your available choices; but fstab should work on all*)

Comment: Please edit your question to give details and specifics about one or more of the partitions that don't mount. Vague generalities lead to wasted time guessing at what you mean.

Comment: I have edited the question, now is it complete? @OrganicMarble

Comment: You've not said if your Ubuntu is a server or desktop install; if it's a server install then *fstab* is the easiest option. Yes Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop has more options, but you've not said what 22.04 system you're using  (ie. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop?  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server? etc), nor what mount methods you tried to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux it works as following.

- By default, the system partition and optionally, any other partition mentioned in the configuration file `/etc/fstab`, are automatically mounted during startup, on a directory as specified in that configuration file.
- Any other internal partition in your computer is *not* mounted. However, they are shown in the left pane of the file manager, and can be mounted by clicking the icon.
- Removable drives are automatically mounted when they are plugged in, in a directory under `/media/<login>/`.

You can configure a partition to mount during startup with the utility Disks.

1. Determine where in the file system you want the drive to be accessible. That is the mount point, a (empty) directory in which, after mounting, the contents of the mounted partition will appear. Eventually create that mount point. For example, you create a directory "Data" under "/media". Then, the mount point of the drive would be `/media/Data`.
2. In the left pane, click the disk where the partition resides.
3. in the right pane, click the partition on the map.
4. Click the icon with the cog wheel and, in the pop-up menu that appears, select "Edit Mount Options...".
5. The "Mount Options" dialog appears. Uncheck "User Session Defaults". Check "Mount at system startup". Optionally check "Show in user interface" if you want the partition to appear in the left column of the file manager. For "Mount Point", fill out the mount point you decided upon in step 1.

After starting again, the drive should be mounted. Make yourself owner of that directory if you want to have read/write access as user. This also can be done with Disks. Now choose "Take Ownership..." from the pop-up menu.